# GTFS SQL Find Closest Routes

Tags: mysql, gtfs

I have a MySQL database setup with GTFS data and I am trying to query the database to return a list of routes (no duplicates) ordered by the distance to the closest stop on each respective route. (Note: The coordinates will change depending on where the user is)

The database is rather large (millions of rows in the stop_times table, 10,000s of rows in the stops table) so I want to make this as efficient as possible.

One thing I tried was to create a temporary table called stop_routes_link (created when the GTFS data is imported into my database) that links stops with routes such that there is an entry for each stop-route pair like so:

```
route_id  |   stop_id
-----------------------
    25    |  366072709
    21    |  366072709
    21    |  194326291
    F     |  60745282
    Q     |  198000482
```

And then I ran this query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT routes.route_short_name AS route_short_name
FROM routes
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lon ) - radians(-75.15972534860013) ) + sin( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * sin( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, stop_routes_link.route_id AS route_id 
    FROM stops
    LEFT JOIN stop_routes_link ON stops.stop_id = stop_routes_link.stop_id ORDER BY distance)
AS stops ON routes.route_id = stops.route_id
ORDER BY stops.distance
```

And it returns:

```
route_short_name
----------------
      23
      23
      12
      12
      9
      21
      38
```

Which is what I want (I know those are the closest routes to that location), except it returns duplicates for routes since I think it is returning an row for each stop on a route.

How do I return only unique routes?  I thought that the "LEFT JOIN" would cause only one row per entry in the routes table but it didn't.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT DINSTINCT routes.route_short_name AS route_short_name
FROM routes
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lon ) - radians(-75.15972534860013) ) + sin( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * sin( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, stop_routes_link.route_id AS route_id 
    FROM stops
    LEFT JOIN stop_routes_link ON stops.stop_id = stop_routes_link.stop_id ORDER BY distance)
AS stops ON routes.route_id = stops.route_id
ORDER BY stops.distance
```

And:

```
SELECT routes.route_short_name AS route_short_name
FROM routes
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) * cos( radians( stops.stop_lon ) - radians(-75.15972534860013) ) + sin( radians(39.94868155755109) ) * sin( radians( stops.stop_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, stop_routes_link.route_id AS route_id 
    FROM stops
    LEFT JOIN stop_routes_link ON stops.stop_id = stop_routes_link.stop_id ORDER BY distance)
AS stops ON routes.route_id = stops.route_id
GROUP BY route_short_name
ORDER BY stops.distance
```

But they both don't return the closest routes they return a random ordered list of routes (I'm not sure how it is calculated) which I'm assuming is because the grouping messes it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I'm assuming is because the grouping messes it up." What grouping?

Comment: @strawberry by grouping I mean it would attach an arbitrary distance to the route because it groups all of the same routes together (takes the first distance value I believe) and then ordered the list in order of distance but it's ends up being wrong because the stop that is attached to the route is not the closest stop on the route. Does that make sense?

Comment: Grouping being from the "GROUP BY" statement

Comment: But only the last query had one of those

Comment: Yes, that statement was referring only to the last two queries. Referring to the "GROUP BY" and "DISTINCT" statements

Comment: That's my point. There is no grouping in the distinct statement. It can have no effect on the result other than to eliminate duplicate results!

Comment: Then do you know what I have wrong that is making it not work?

Comment: If your first query is correct then the second query must also be correct (although the inner order by clause is redundant - a i guess inner joins will suffice). The third query is incorrect, for reasons you've hinted at.

Comment: Yea that is why I am so confused as to why it is not working.  Is the one row it is selecting not the row with the closest stop maybe?

Comment: We're talking about the second query? It's not selecting only one row !?!

Comment: It is returning a list of unique routes like I want, but it is not ordering them correctly.

Comment: That's a completely different issue. Please try to be clear. How do you want them ordered?

Comment: I want a list of routes (without duplicates) that is ordered starting with the routes that pass through the closest stop to the coordinates. For example, for the coordinates provided, the stop closest to that point is a stop for route 23, the second closest stop is a stop for routes 12, 9, and 21, etc.

Comment: It's just not possible that your second query orders the result any differently from your first.

Comment: First Query: http://i.imgur.com/Ai1FnAO.png    Second Query: http://i.imgur.com/BlQIaz7.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I'm so confused by this too.  Any idea why?

Comment: It's confusing that an alias to a derived table shares its name with that of an actual table. Can you change that, and then perhaps include the distance in the select clause, so we can see that they're all different. Also, an sqlfiddle is generally more useful than images.